# How to test for a specific ProviderNotFoundException in widget test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I have some providers (e.g provider A,B,C) created above a certain widget and testing the `ProviderNotFoundException` in the case that a provider was removed from the widget tree.

Right now I'm testing the `ProviderNotFoundException` like this:

```dart
expect(tester.takeException(), isA<ProviderNotFoundException>());
```

This is very generic because this will work for all the Providers A,B and C if they were removed. I would like to add additional constraints to check if only Provider B was not found.

I tried using the `having` method on the `isA` but could not get it to work.

```dart
expect(
              tester.takeException(),
              isA<ProviderNotFoundException>().having(
                (e) => e.valueType,
                'valueType',
                contains('A'),
              ));
```

Comment: `having` should be the way to go - Do you mind posting the code you tried with having?

Comment: @MichaelHorn I realized my error. The `matcher` argument should have the type  of the Provider and not check if it contains the name of the Provider. I will post the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `having` method to add additional constraints and check if the `feature` argument matches the `matcher` argument correctly.

```dart
 expect(
              tester.takeException(),
              isA<ProviderNotFoundException>().having(
                (e) => e.valueType,
                'valueType',
                A,
              ));
```